# How to consume post/put WCF RestFul Service

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, wcf-rest

I am doing crud operation(Using Stored Procedure)  in wcf restful service .I have done with creating services,but How do I consume that service in my **plain ASP.net Application(without Javascript,Jquery,AJAX)**. As I am new in WCF rest service.Plz give me step by step operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         string sURL =  @"http://localhost:50353/urUriName/"+ txtfname.Text;
        WebRequest webGETURL;

        webGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
       webGETURL.Method = "DELETE"; 
       webGETURL.ContentType = @"Application/Json; charset=utf-8";
      HttpWebResponse wr = webGETURL.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
       Encoding enc=Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    // read response stream from response object
    StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream(), enc);

    // read string from stream data
    string strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

    // close the stream object
    loResponseStream.Close();
    // close the response object
    wr.Close();
    // assign the final result to text box
    Response.Write(strResult);
```